# What about a new search tab? my tags tab

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

When I'm searching the site, it would be nice if I can see the results in "My Tags" order.

**How it should work?**

Lets say that the user that is searching now has the following tags on his list: (took from [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2509/dmckee))

```
c++× 126
latex× 71
linux× 56
language-agnostic× 33
unix× 33
math× 29
algorithm× 28
emacs× 23
bash× 21
```

When he searchs the site, and prefers to see it in "My tags" order, it means that questions with `c++` tag going first, then `latex` tag, etc...

Answer (score 1):

They could add a parameter of **myinttags:1** or something like that to the advanced search options.

Comment: This might be the way to go, but ::checks SO profile:: I seem to have activity in more than 700 tags ::boggles::, so I don't think it will help *me* much...

Comment: @dmckee, It's not in what tags you have activity I'm referring to, but to the tags you have marked as 'Interesting'.

Comment: Ah. That's better, I think.

Comment: @dmckee: I edited the post.

Comment: @dmckee, looks like I misunderstood what the OP wanted, I'll redo my answer as a different feature request.

Comment: @Lance Roberts: you understood correct. but after I saw  @dmckee comment I think this is make much more sense to that in this way.

Comment: @Mendy, I've added a feature-request for this here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40117/add-advanced-search-option-to-search-within-a-users-interesting-ignored-tags