# Add advanced search option to search within a user's Interesting/Favorite/Ignored Tags

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, ignored-tags, search

I think we should be able to search with our Interesting/Favorite Tags or our Ignored Tags, something like:

**myfavtags:1  "test"**

or

**myigntags:1  "test"**

I'm open to other ways of doing this also.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/search-in-list-of-favorited-questions Apparently this was implemented for a few months, then disabled, then marked as "deferred" (just the favorites part of the request, not the ignores half).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search for questions tagged with your favorite tags using [`intags:mine`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=intags:mine) search term in search box.

You can add additional terms as well: [`intags:mine select`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intags:mine%20select)

However there is no option to search for questions tagged with your ignored tags. And I don't understand why anyone would want to search for questions which are tagged with his ignored tags.

Comment: Actually, just testing I found that it added a "NOT" and my ignored tags to the query.  So it won't search in the ignored tags, but it takes them into account.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps we could mimic the `user:` syntax and do `fav:me` and `ignored:294052`?