# How can I search my favorite questions only?

Tags: feature-request, search, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search in list of favorited questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/search-in-list-of-favorited-questions)
>   [Add advanced search option to search within a user's Interesting/Favorite/Ignored Tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40117/add-advanced-search-option-to-search-within-a-users-interesting-favorite-ignored)

How can I search my favorite questions only? is it possible to do that?

Comment: And better yet, given Nick's answer: [Reimplement the broken searching within favorites functionality](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78946/reimplement-the-broken-searching-within-favorites-functionality/79956#79956).